# Replace certain text in the MySQL column

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I have a table `items` and an `item_name` column inside of it, and I would like to replace certain text that column has, for example table `items` contains the following:

> Steel Sword
>
> Brozne Sword
>
> Gold Sword

Then I would like to replace only the `Sword` string to `Axe` for all items at once. I've tried to use the MySQL's `REPLACE()` function, but it doesn't work for some reason...
If it's possible, how can I replace that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you tell why `UPDATE items SET item_name = REPLACE(item_name, 'Sword', 'Axe');` is not working? What's the result?

Comment: He might not want to modify the data

Comment: Seems like I have missed something, because your example worked for me. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, if you want for displaying purposes on use `SELECT`

```
SELECT item_name, replace(item_name, 'Sword','Axe')
FROM items
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02abf/3)

but if you want the value to permanently change, use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE items
SET item_name = replace(item_name, 'Sword','Axe')
```

**Note: REPLACE() is CASE SENSITIVE**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE item_name when "Sword" then "Axe"
ELSE item_name
END
FROM TBL
```